# Why are my if statements not working in this for loop?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, runnable

### Question:

I'm designing a small Android app that plays sounds (notes) when you press an imageButton that looks like a specific instrument, and you can play up to 10 notes across 6 imageButtons. It stores the note number in an array and sets the element to a specific number.
*This part seems to work fine*

The app has a feature that lets you play back what you recently played. For some reason this only plays the first note 10 times - it doesn't seem to understand the new array values so it always gets hung up on the first if statement in the for loop. I need it to read the new array values so it can play back what the user played on the given instrument.

### Code:

```
public void drum1button(View view) { //This code snippet works as expected
    if (studio.drumCount < 10){
        new Thread(drum.drum1).start();
        drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = 0;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),studio.drumCount + " drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = " + drum.drums[studio.drumCount],2).show();

        studio.drumCount++;
    }
    else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Record limit reached. Head to the studio!",5).show();
    }
}


public void drum2button(View view) {
if (studio.drumCount < 10){
    new Thread(drum.drum2).start();
    drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = 1;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),studio.drumCount + " drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = " + drum.drums[studio.drumCount],2).show();

    studio.drumCount++;

}
else {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Record limit reached. Head to the studio!",5).show();
}
}


public void drum3button(View view) {
    if (studio.drumCount <10 ) {
    new Thread(drum.drum3).start();
    drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = 2;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),studio.drumCount + " drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = " + drum.drums[studio.drumCount],2).show();

    studio.drumCount++;
    }
    else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Record limit reached. Head to the studio!",5).show();
    }

}

public void drum4button(View view) {
    if (studio.drumCount < 10) {
    new Thread(drum.drum4).start();
    drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = 3;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),studio.drumCount + " drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = " + drum.drums[studio.drumCount],2).show();

    studio.drumCount++;
    }
    else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Record limit reached. Head to the studio!",5).show();
    }
}

public void drum5button(View view) {
    if (studio.drumCount < 10) {
    new Thread(drum.drum5).start();
    drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = 4;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),studio.drumCount + " drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = " + drum.drums[studio.drumCount],2).show();

    studio.drumCount++;
    }

    else {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Record limit reached. Head to the studio!",5).show();
    }
}

public void drum6button(View view) {
    if (studio.drumCount < 10){
    new Thread(drum.drum6).start();
    drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = 5;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),studio.drumCount + " drum.drums[studio.drumCount] = " + drum.drums[studio.drumCount],2).show();

    studio.drumCount++;
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Record limit reached. Head to the studio!",5).show();

    }
}
```

---

```
Runnable drumPlayback = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { //(was i = 10, typo in formatting when //pasting. Still does not work with i = 0
        //handler.postDelayed(drumPlayback, 5000);

        try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch(Exception e) {}
         if (drum.drums[i] == 0) { 
          new Thread(drum.drum1).start(); //this is the only one that plays

          }
          if (drum.drums[i] == 1) { 
          new Thread(drum.drum2).start(); 
          } 
         if (drum.drums[i] == 2) { 
          new Thread(drum.drum3).start(); 
          } 
           if (drum.drums[i] == 3) { 
          new Thread(drum.drum4).start(); 
          } 
           if (drum.drums[i] == 4) { 
          new Thread(drum.drum5).start(); 
          } 
           if (drum.drums[i] == 5) {
          new Thread(drum.drum6).start(); 
                    }
                }
            }
    };
```

Comment: Can you debug your drums array to check if the values in the array are correct?

Answer (score 4):

The loop condition is `i < 10` but you init i with 10. So the loop will never start.

Comment: :) for (int i = 10; i < 10; i++)  is so obvious. I think she/he was testing peoples skills and reaction time! At least he/she should select your answer as a correct one :)

Comment: Well, because of that lil' fails i have a syso in my loops at the first time :)

Comment: Oh, it looks so obvious but I was editing code. I can change it to i = 0 and the problem persists. Only the first sound file plays.

Comment: IMO the code should work, means the other classes (drum, studio) include the misbehaviour. Without the other code i can just guess that the drumcounter somehow will be set to 0.